# customize the height of tab indicator in view pager?

Tags: android, view, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator, android-styles

I am looking to style the tab indicator like pininterest where the indicator does not look like the normal "android" style . Is there some attribute where i can set the indicator height ?Please look into the following image .

[image]

Answer (score 0):

just set layout_height attribute in your layout file:

```
com.viewpagerindicator.TitlePageIndicator
android:layout_height="@dimen/indicator_height"
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be not a proper solution, and question is really old, but as I haven't found any proper solutions, this is how I did it:

I created a layerList file called indicator:

```
<layer-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#FF0000" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:bottom="3dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#efefef" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

And just set it as my tab indicator background:

```
<style name="CustomTabPageIndicator" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabView">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/indicator</item>
    </style>
```

I've also applied this theme to my actionBar:

```
<style name="MyActionBarTheme" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
             <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/CustomTabPageIndicator</item>
        </item> </style>
```

It works because in indicator.xml first shape is lower shape, which is actual indicator, and to I set its height by providing bottom padding for another shape which color is identical to actionbar color.

Answer (score 0):

Using the material design TabLayout, You can set the height with `app:tabIndicatorHeight`

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp" />
```